Testing with spring boot, H2, Gradle not working
Here's an overview of my setup:

I have a Spring Boot application configured with Gradle.
I'm using an embedded H2 database for testing purposes, while in another environment I use PostgreSQL.
My test class ClientRepositoryTest is annotated with @DataJpaTest and contains the SQL script data.sql located at src/test/resources.

Test Class ->
@DataJpaTest
@Sql("classpath:data.sql")
class ClientRepositoryTest {
....

data.sql(src/test/resources)
insert into public.product (id_product,name) VALUES
(79104,'LOAD'),
(79204,'TRANSPORT');

When I run the test form IntellJ or from gradle command (gradle clean build), I get the next error, when my class Product is
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_product")
    private Integer idProduct;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.PRODUCT(ID_PRODUCT) ( / key:79104 / 79104, 'LOAD ...
I don't understand, because there is not data.
Thank you for your help.

You need active test profile, with data source pointed to embed database.
